# Duplicated, interlaced and distorted graphics on my HP dv6000

Tags: 11.04, nvidia, graphics, live-cd

#### Issue

When I boot from the live USB, after selecting "Try Ubuntu ..." all graphics are interlaced, shifted to the right, duplicated and distorted -- Even the terminal when I access it by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd>.

[image]

Unity is also disabled. <sup>*why would you call that a problem, some might say*</sup>

#### Information

Ubuntu version
**11.04**

Boot media
**USB**

Graphics card

`lspci | grep -i VGA` states

```
00:12.0 VGA compatible controller: nVidia Corporation C67 \
[GeForce 7150M /nForce 630M] (rev a2) 2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you are affected by this bug

[Launchpad Bug 597476](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers/+bug/597476)

There was a work around posted by [Cristian Arezzini](https://launchpad.net/~macavity80)

Still about the Natty beta... I tried to change the resolution to 1280x800, but it wasn't available on the monitor preferences window. To enable it, I had to uncheck the "same image on all monitors" box - then all the resolutions are available. Without unchecking that box, only the resolutions also good for TV output are available. And all of those are corrupted (striped) on this video card.
It would be really nice to fix all the resolutions, but at least to set the default to the correct (1280x800) resolution, so that the system works "out of the box"...

Comment: Not helpful since I do not run a dual-monitor setup on that particular system.

Comment: The "BUG" is that the driver is set-up by default as if the second display were plugged EVEN WHEN IT IS NOT thus causing the display corruption have you tried changing the resolution?

Comment: THe bug in the bug is that it does not appear as if two displays are connected, I've checked the monitor preferences.

Comment: What resolution is your screen set to at the moment? Judging by the shape of the icons it is in a 4:3 ratio and your laptop screen is wide..... 16:9

Comment: After putting the PC in sleepmode and waking it up again, your description fits perfectly. Thank you!